# How to display the content of a dictionary in a TableLayoutPanel in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, tablelayoutpanel

I need to display in a TableLayoutPanel called `ucOutputPredictionsResults` the content of a dictionary called `predictionDictionary` and have in the first column the name and in the second column a value. All keys and values have type string in my dictionary.

I can display the key and the value, but not in the order I request

Here's what I've done :

```
this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.RowCount = 0;
this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.ColumnCount = 0;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in (_testExecution as TestExecutionAlveoGraph)
                                             .predictionDictionary)
{
   Label lb = new Label();
   lb.Text = kvp.Key;

   this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.Controls.Add(lb,
             this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.ColumnCount,
             this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.RowCount);

   Label valueLbl = new Label();
   valueLbl.Text = kvp.Value;

   this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.Controls.Add(valueLbl,
            this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.ColumnCount +1, 
            this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.RowCount);
}
```

but the result is not what I expect :

[image]

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: You are relying on the TLP's layout to grow the cols and rows you need. But when adding the 1st control you force it to place it somewhere, right? For this it has to create both a column and a row!! Now colcount and rowCount are 1 hence the 2nd label will be added to row 1, not 0 etc.. - Best create the right numbers and calculate the right indices yourself..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I agree with TaW that you should explicitly setup your TableLayoutPanel and add controls in a more controlled manner, you could fix the "problem" by setting ColumnCount to 2 and using the overload of Add() that receives only a control.  The Labels will be added as expected then.

Simplified code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.Controls.Clear();
    this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.RowCount = 0;
    this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.ColumnCount = 2;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in _testExecution)
    {
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = kvp.Key;

        this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.Controls.Add(lb);

        Label valueLbl = new Label();
        valueLbl.Text = kvp.Value;

        this.ucOutputPredictionsResults.Controls.Add(valueLbl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly good. Sorry for the lack of information but I'm new as a developer. I'll do better next time. Thanks again.